# "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW"

Tags: node.js, forms, reactjs

[desc table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC1YW.png)

There is NULL set as default in database

[form.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehimY.png)

After submit it sends error : "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW"

Anyone got some idea please?

Answer (score 2):

You encounter this kind of error when there is a mismatch between:

- the number of values you want to insert
- the number of columns you have in your table

Have you tried inserting the exact number of values and not assuming the default value of your table will do the job ?

One other possibility is this error: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67863

I don't know if the MySQL team has already solved this problem but it might also be your case.